# JOINING two tables a WHERE and a SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum, where-clause

I have this table called sales:

```
vat,    activation
12345   2017-07-28
567892  2018-08-21
224124  2016-08-22
```

and this table called invoices:

```
cif,   billdate,    amount
12345  2017-07-19   200
12345  2017-07-29   250
12345  2017-08-02   3000
224124 2016-08-24   400
224124 2018-09-08   2499
```

I want to get a table like this:

```
vat,   activation, first_month_amount
12345  2017-07-28  450
224124 2016-08-22  400
567892 2018-08-21  200
```

Basically the sum of all invocies billed on the month of activation.

So far I tried this:

```
select * from  sales
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT vat,sum(amount) as first_month_amount
    FROM invoices 
    WHERE month(billdate)=month(activation) 
    Group by cif
    ) as salesdata on sales.vat = salesdata.cif
```

The query fails because it cannot find the activation column.

Second try was:

```
select * from  sales
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT vat,sum(amount) as first_month_amount
    FROM invoices 
    WHERE month(billdate)=month(activation) 
    Group by cif
    ) as salesdata on sales.vat = salesdata.cif
```

It fails again because it cannot find the billdate column

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the desired results. It groups sales by year-month as well as `cif` and makes the `JOIN` on the year-month and the `cif` values:

```
SELECT s.vat, s.activation, COALESCE(i.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cif, DATE_FORMAT(billdate, '%Y%m') AS billmonth, SUM(amount) AS amount
           FROM invoices
           GROUP BY cif, billmonth) i ON i.cif = s.vat AND i.billmonth = DATE_FORMAT(s.activation, '%Y%m')
```

Output (note 0 value for `vat = 567892` because no data in `invoices`):

```
vat     activation  amount
12345   2017-07-28  450
567892  2018-08-21  0
224124  2016-08-22  400
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ufC6LpkJnqY8UUqxeyjvQ/3)

Comment: It did the trick ! Thanks a lot Nick, I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to utilize [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html); Also, just matching months is not enough, you will need to match the year as well, to correctly get "first month" amount:

```
select s.*, 
       (select sum(i.amount) 
        from invoices i 
        where month(i.billdate) = month(s.activation) 
              and year(i.billdate) = year(s.activation) 
              and i.cif = s.vat
       ) first_month_amount
from  sales s
```

Above query can be *performant* by having index `(cif)` on `invoices` table. So, if you have not defined this index yet; you can use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE invoices ADD INDEX (cif);
```

But, this query is still not optimized well enough (atleast, as per me). Currently, using `Month()` and `Year()` functions on the date value are inhibiting the usage of index on `billdate` field of the `invoices` table.

So, we can make the query sargeable as follows:

```
select s.*, 
       (select sum(i.amount) 
        from invoices i 
        where i.cif = s.vat 
              and i.billdate 
                    between date_format(s.activation, '%Y-%m-01') 
                            and last_day(s.activation)
       ) first_month_amount
from  sales s
```

This query will be *performant enough*, if we define the following composite index on the `invoices` table. Note that `billdate` should come at end of index, as it is Range condition:

```
ALTER TABLE invoices ADD INDEX (cif, billdate);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the knowledge and recommendations Madhur !

Comment: @Mamut you are welcome ! You should benchmark various approaches in all the answers here, before coming to a conclusion. Having (and continuously gaining) practical exp on tables having millions of rows, [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) based techniques cause unncessary temp table creation and eventually affect other queries running on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select vat, activation,first_month_amount
from sales s
(
SELECT cif,month(billdate) mbill,year(billdate) ybill,sum(amount) as first_month_amount
    FROM invoices 
    Group by cif,month(billdate),year(billdate)
)s1 on s.vat=s1.cif and month(activation)=mbill and year(activation)=ybill
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a join between tables:

```
select s.vat, s.activation, sum(i.amount)
from sales s
 left join invoices i on last_day(i.billdate)=last_day(s.activation)
group by s.vat, s.activation;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec5470/5)

Not sure about the logic of the last expected row (567892 2018-08-21  200) as there is no data to produce that.